# Listing datasets in a group in HDF5

Tags: python, hdf5

I decided to store my data in HDF5 using its hierarchical structure instead of relying on the filesystem.
Unfortunately, I'm having performance issues.

My data is formatted as follows:
I have about 70 top level groups, corresponding to dates and each of them contain roughly 8000 datasets.
I would like to see a list of the number of datasets per day:

```
for date in hdf5.keys():
   print(len(hdf5[date]))
```

I'm finding it a little frustrating that this takes 2+ second/iteration.

Also, I have two different hdf5 files with the above layout and the bigger one is much slower at this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you really just want to see what datasets are in the file, I would use the `h5dump` or `h5stat` utilities. For example `h5stat --dset <file>` will print information about all the datasets in the file. If you want less detailed information, just use `h5dump -n <file>`, which will print the general file contents, similar to an `ls -l`.

Comment: @bnaecker: I'm looking for a solution in python actually. But running h5stat --dset took 4 minutes and 10 seconds :(

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the file with the libver latest flag:

```
f = h5py.File('name.hdf5', libver='latest')
```

This will be much faster if you have a lot of datasets per group or attributes per dataset.

Comment: Thank you John. I didn't %timeit, but there doesn't seem to be a visible speed up from the 2-3 sec/read

Comment: What is the version of the hdf5 library that you are using? I created a file with 70 groups each with 8000 datasets and was able to do the loop you describe in 0.45 sec (for the entire file).

Comment: Also, you might see improvements by just having: "for date in hdf5" rather than: "for date in hdf5.keys()".

Comment: Thanks again John. Unfortunately, the problem seems to be the size of the hdf5 file. The code runs considerably faster on a 5 GB file than on a 20 GB file (with the same layout)

Comment: Also, I don't think .keys() is a problem, I'm using python 3 where it returns a view anyway