# How to save list of numpy.arrays of different shape with h5py?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I'm saving a large dataset of images (flickr25k dataset) into hdf5 using h5py. However image are different in size, thus I can't create a dataset with shape `(nb_images, height, width)`.

Now I'm using multiple datasets to handle this problem. Thus `create_dataset('image1', shape=shape1)` , `create_dataset('image2', shape=shape2)` , etc.

In python we can use a list to save multiple `numpy.array` with different size easily. I'm wondering if we can do the same thing with h5py, and fetch data with syntax like:

```
images = h5file.get('images')
images[id_img][:,:]
```

Comment: Search other `h5py` tagged questions. For example http://stackoverflow.com/q/41496953.  `h5py` organizes groups and sets as dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm currently using method just like the example you mentioned. The reason I ask this question is that I'm just wondering if there is a grace method other than iterating all items or storing all keys into a list.