# Efficiently store list of matrices

Tags: python, numpy, pickle, pytables, h5py

I have a large list of images stored as numpy matrices. The images have different sizes e.g.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

data = [rand(100,200), rand(1024, 768)]
```

I am looking for a way to store this list of matrices such that it can be read fast (writing the data can be slow). I tried pickle/numpy.savez, but reading the data was slower than loading the raw images again.

I think hdf5 may be fast, however I cannot figure out how to store this list. Not mandatory, but useful would data format which allows to append data such that the list does not have to in memory as a whole.

**Edit:**
Based on the answers so far I tried to time some suggestions

```
data = [rand(1024, 768) for i in np.arange(100)]
def timenp():
    np.savez("test.npz",*data)
    d=np.load('test.npz')
    loaded = [d[f] for f in d]

def timebinary():
    with file("tmp.bin","wb") as f:
        np.save(f, len(data))
        for img in data:
            np.save(f,img)

    with file("tmp.bin","rb") as f:
        n = np.load(f)
        loaded = []
        for i in np.arange(n):
            loaded.append(np.load(f))

import h5py
def timeh5py():
    with h5py.File('foo.hdf5','w') as f:
        dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.dtype('float32'))
        dset = f.create_dataset('data', (len(data),), dtype=dt)
        shapes = f.create_dataset('shapes', (len(data), 2), dtype='int32')
        dset[...] = [img.flatten() for img in data]
        shapes[...] = [img.shape for img in data]

    with h5py.File('foo.hdf5','r') as f:
        loaded=[]
        for (img, shape) in zip(f['data'],f['shapes']):
            loaded.append(np.reshape(img,shape))
```

---

> python -m cProfile timenp.py
>            452906 function calls (451141 primitive calls) in 9.256 seconds

---

> python -m cProfile timebinary.py
>           73085 function calls (71340 primitive calls) in 4.945 seconds

---

> python -m cProfile timeh5py.py
>           33151 function calls (32568 primitive calls) in 4.384 seconds

Comment: How are you loading the raw images?

Comment: `scipy.ndimage.imread`

Comment: Assuming `imread` is using compiled code from the PIL library I don't expect `numpy` saves to be any faster.  Though that may be depend on the image format (`jpeg` may be require added processing).

Comment: Your second timing is for successive 'save' writes to the same file.  I'm not surprised that it is faster, since it doesn't have to go through the `zip` archive mechanism.  That multiple saves works has been demonstrated in previous SO questions, but it seems to be an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [numpy savez function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) , which comes in both compressed and uncompressed versions.

Comment: I tried it, but it seems that `np.savez("test.npz",data=data)` stores the list using pickle, which is too slow.

Comment: You might want to try using a fast compression algorithm to cut down on IO time, like [google's snappy compression](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-snappy).

It looks like someone has asked a question similar to yours about 
[hd5 saving of numpy arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928136/input-and-output-numpy-arrays-to-h5py)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [276]: alist=[np.arange(10), np.arange(3), np.arange(100)]
```

If I save this as `np.savez('test',alist)`, it saves the list as one object.  If instead I expand the list with `*`, then it puts each list element is a separate file in the archive.

```
In [277]: np.savez('test',*alist)
In [278]: d=np.load('test.npz')
In [279]: list(d.keys())
Out[279]: ['arr_2', 'arr_1', 'arr_0']
In [280]: d['arr_0']
Out[280]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

With `np.save` (and by extension `savez`), arrays are stored in their own compact format, which consists of a header block with shape information, and the data block, which is essentially a byte copy of its data buffer.  So a `np.save` of an array should be as efficient any other method.

If you give `np.save` an non-array object it will use that object's pickle method.  But note that the pickle method for an array is the `save` method I just described.  So a pickle of an array should still be efficient.

Keep in mind that `npz` files are lazy-loaded.

With `h5py`, arrays are saved to named data sets.  In sense it is like the `savez` above - the elements of the list have to have names, whether generated automatically or by your code.

I don't know how `h5py` speeds compare with a `save(z)`.

`h5py` can handle arrays that are ragged in one dimension.  I've explored that in previous SO questions.  [Storing multidimensional variable length array with h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658438/storing-multidimensional-variable-length-array-with-h5py)

[How to save list of numpy.arrays of different shape with h5py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406376/how-to-save-list-of-numpy-arrays-of-different-shape-with-h5py)